# how to query key Angularfire2

Tags: javascript, ionic2, angularfire2

How can i query the users node. i tried using

```
            return this.db.list('groups/', {
              query: {
                orderByChild: 'users',
                equalTo: uid
              }
            });
```

[image]

Comment: you cannot do it ins single query

Comment: how do i go about it

Comment: @netx , you found any answer?

Comment: No!!, i had to rewrite my functions

Answer (score 0):

Your query is definitely not going to work. There are a few solutions that come to mind:
1 - if you have the groupUid:

```
groupUid = "asdasdafd";
return this.db.list('groups/'+this.groupUid+'/users', {
          query: {
            equalTo: uid
          }
        });
```

or something like this:

```
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
groupUid = "asdasdafd";
return this.db.list('groups/'+this.groupUid+'/users')
    .filter(item => item==uid);
```

2 - if you don't have the groupUid:
you need to receive the `this.db.object('groups/')` object , and after that iterate with simple loop(over all users) inside loop(over all groups) to search for `uid` you need.
something like:

```
for(var prop in groups){
  for(var j=0;j<prop.users.length;j++){
    //search the uid you need
  }
}
```

hope its helped you.